# Entity Framework 7 SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework-core

Is there any way to register a callback that will be called before a model in EF7 is saved to the database? What I want to do is to set a ModifiedBy and ModifiedDate property that I have on all models. I'm not that keen to do this manually before each save so I'm looking for some more generic and automatic way.

Comment: Have you seen [Generated properties](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/generated-properties.html)?

Comment: From what I understand Generated Properties are used to mark that the property can be set by the database. I want to set the property in my c# code in a generic way that ensures that it happens on every save.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ChangeTracker.Entries()` allows you to get all of the entity changes. You could override `SaveChanges` in your DbContext and set the modified properties using something like the following code.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    SetModifiedInformation();
    return base.SaveChanges();
}

public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync( CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken() )
{
    SetModifiedInformation();
    return await base.SaveChangesAsync( cancellationToken );
}

private void SetModifiedInformation()
{
    foreach (var entityEntry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        var entity = entityEntry.Entity as ChangeTracking;
        if (entity != null)
        {
            entity.ModifiedBy = "Get User Here";
            entity.ModifiedTime = DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should one check for entityEntry.State != EntityState.Unchanged && entityEntry.State != EntityState.Detached aswell?

Comment: Yes that would be good to make sure that entities are not marked as modified when they shouldn't be