# Update MemoryCache web.api when saving data in database using Entity Framework core

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have cached some data from the database in my web.api core, and when I am updating some of the tables that has been cached, I would like to update my cache in the api. Right now I am doing this by calling a method everywhere if it is needed, when I am doing "SaveChanges". But Can it somehow be done easier ? Maybe subscribe to an event, or overwrite "saveChanges" in api ?

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Comment: overwrite "saveChanges" could do that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951613/entity-framework-7-savechanges

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! I already know about overwriting SaveChanges, but the problem is that SaveChanges is in my DAL layer and the cache is in the API. The DAL doesn't know anything about the cache. So I was thinking about making the SaveChanges throw an event every time an entity that is in the cache is saved/updated, and then subscribe to that event in the api. But I am not sure how to implement that?